# Bold font problem while using Russian fonts

Tags: bold, r

This refers to my previous question

[not able to write bold characters using textbf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84603/not-able-to-write-bold-characters-using-textbf)

I installed the cm-extra font package but still there is a problem with boldface due to `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{myboldtt}
\def\n{\textbackslash n}
\begin{document}
  Regular text. \textbf{Bold}.
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
%chunk = 1
<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
cat("dataset","\n")
cat("\textbf{dataset}","\n")   # it should be bold 
@
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Please help me out in fixing this problem as I'm in great need.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the cm-super-fonts don't provide a bold typewriter font. But the lmodern fonts do but only for T1-encoding. So you should temporarly switch the font encoding to T1 (or the language to english). On the other side the lmodern font don't provide a bold T2A-font (needed for the regular text). So you should switch only the typewriter font e.g. to lmodern or to the luximono fonts (which have a more distinctive bold version):

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
%typewriter is lmodern:
\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmtt}
%Alternative:
%\usepackage[scaled]{luximono}

\def\n{\textbackslash n}
\begin{document}
Regular text. \textbf{Bold}.

\begingroup
\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
%chunk = 1
<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
cat("dataset","\n")
cat("\textbf{dataset}","\n")   # it should be bold
@
\end{Verbatim}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used above code still same pblm.

Comment: @Manish: Did you use exactly my code or some adaption? In the first case: Put the log-file and the pdf somewhere for inspection.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with font encoding has been solved in the `Sweave` package. You should use param `[noae]` in header, like `\usepackage[noae]{Sweave}`. This param forces `Sweave` to use T1 encoding and the problem with bold russian fonts is gone. For additional info, see the [R newsletter](http://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-2.pdf), page 42.

Comment: I joined this community to thank you for the answer. Only this method worked for me!

Comment: Thank you @user56091! You have saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

The example by Fischer works for me but conflicts with `Sweave` package. After compiling .Rnw file and creating .tex file I had to comment `Sweave` (`%\usepackage{Sweave}`)  in `.tex` file and after compiling `.tex` to a `.PDF` file bold font showed up in output.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.